# swift: can a class or a struct have a kind of "main" property which can accessed without dot notation?

Tags: swift, properties

I am using a static struct to namespace my app's constants. Actually, they are not constants but variables, so later on the user could change some of them.

A lot of them are metrics that are dependant on the font size, therefore nested into the struct is another struct, which holds the desired size relative to the font size, but whenever the app accesses one of these constants, the final value is calculated.

Here is a little code example:

```
public struct ApplicationConstants {

    public static var fontSize: Double = 24

    public struct RelativeSize {
        public var size: Double

        public init(_ size: Double) {
            self.size = size
        }

        public var double: Double {
            return size * fontSize
        }
    }
    public static var offsetAfterBulletPoint: RelativeSize = RelativeSize(0.3)
}

print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint.double) // returns 7.2
ApplicationConstants.fontSize = 16
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint.double) // returns 4.8
```

For better readability I would much prefer if I simply could access the resulting value without explicitly calling the .double calculated property, like this:

```
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint)
```

as this value is the only value which will ever be needed by the app itself. The stored relative-to-fontsize value is only meant to be presented within a possible preferences pane, where the relation to the fontsize is much more understandable than the resulting value.

I could store the value directly as a double and doing the calculation upon initialization:

```
public static var offsetAfterBulletPoint: Double = fontSize*0.3
```

but then I would have to implement a willSet observer into the fontSize var to recalculate every single font-dependant value, whenever the font size changes. In my app there will probably be 100s of such font related values.

So, is there a protocol or something else, which could make the .double var of my nested RelativeSize struct a kind of "first respond property" which will be returned when calling the variable without specifying a member, so that it behaves if it were a primitive?

Comment: I'd recommend against using statics in this case. I guarentee you're going to run into a case where you're going two want two `ApplicationConstants`, with differing values.

Comment: Do you need the inner struct? You could have all those variables as static.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

Method 1: **Using Computed Property**

```
public struct ApplicationConstants {
    public static var fontSize: Double = 24
    public static var offsetAfterBulletPoint: Double {
        return fontSize * 0.3
    }
}

print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint) // returns 7.2
ApplicationConstants.fontSize = 16
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint) // returns 4.8
```

Method 2: **Using Static Function**

If you want resize factor to be known to user.

```
public static func offsetAfterBulletPoint(with factor: Double) -> Double {
    return fontSize * factor
}
```

Method 3: **Using Closure**

```
public static let offsetAfterBulletPoint: ((Double) -> Double) = { factor in
    return fontSize * factor
}
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint(0.3)) // returns 7.2
ApplicationConstants.fontSize = 16
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint(0.3)) // returns 4.8
```

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, no. I must be able to expose the 0.3 value to the user so that this value can be changed. In your solution it would be hardcoded.

Comment: @MassMover So extract the `0.3` factor into another variable, but keep using a computed property as shown here.

Comment: @MassMover: Thanks for clarifying your reasons. I have added some other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this in your case:

```
public struct ApplicationConstants {

    public static var fontSize: Double = 24

    public struct RelativeSize {
        public var size: Double

        public init(_ size: Double) {
            self.size = size
        }

        public var double: Double {
            return size * fontSize
        }
    }
    private static var _offsetAfterBulletPoint: RelativeSize = RelativeSize (0.3)

    public static var offsetAfterBulletPoint : Double {
        get {
            return _offsetAfterBulletPoint.double
        } set {
            _offsetAfterBulletPoint = RelativeSize(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you get you will get the calculated value. And if you set, you can set the relative size initializer:

```
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint) // prints 7.2
ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint = 0.4
print(ApplicationConstants.offsetAfterBulletPoint) // prints 9.6
```

Or you can play a bit with the variables if you don't like using the same property to set and get your values

Comment: Ok, using _ivars actually would get me the desired behaviour. I was hoping there was maybe a less verbose way, though...